# how to update the AWS Lambda index.js file

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I updated the `index.js` file as below, `handler = index.handler` and runtime= Node.js 14.x

```js
function handler(event, context, callback){    
    var 
        city_str = event.city_str,
        response = {
            city_str: city_str,
            temp_int: 74
        };
    console.log(response);
    callback(null, response);
}
exports.handler = handler;
```

but it giving the output only of default index.js file as below

```json
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Hello from Lambda!\""
}
```

what could be the issue?

Comment: You need to provide details about how you are deploying and running your function.

Comment: If you have made the change through the AWS Console. You probably just forgot to push the `Deploy` button.